# Regex: Match everything between dots, but exclude entire word if parenthesis is found

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to find a regex pattern that allows me to match dot separated words past `config.`, but not match any words that have open parenthesis. Example:

- `config.hello.world` should match `hello.world`
- `config.hello` should match `hello`
- `config.hello.world(` should match `hello`
- `config.hello.world*10` should match `hello.world`

I've been unable to figure out the parenthesis part. The first, second, and fourth example above I've gotten to work via

```regex
\bconfig\.([\w\.]+)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\bconfig\.([\w.]+)\b(?![(\w])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y2a7f6/2). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `config\.` - a `config.` substring
- `([\w.]+)` - Group 1: one or more word or `.` chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?![(\w])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word or `(` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pFZGFM):

```py
import re
texts = ['config.hello.world','config.hello','config.hello','config.hello.world']
rx = re.compile(r'\bconfig\.([\w.]+)(?![(\w])')
for text in texts:
    m = rx.search(text)
    if m:
        print(text + " => " + m.group(1))
    else:
        print(text + " => NO MATCH")
```

Output:

```
config.hello.world => hello.world
config.hello => hello
config.hello => hello
config.hello.world => hello.world
```

Comment: @Felipe You can do all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. I have a [YT channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), where you can learn more about regex.

Comment: Unsure why my previous comments got deleted, but nonetheless, thank you very much!

Comment: Comment was used to ask for more information ... but I digress since now we are _really_ getting off-topic.